# Preprocess ng-repeat variables?

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to print the output in div. Elements in `bCrumbs` collection  start with slash and space and I want to remove them from 1st loop iteration.

My Code:

```
<div ng-repeat="bCrumb in bCrumbs" id="{{bCrumb.name}}">{{ bCrumb.name }}</div>
```

the output from `{{ bCrumb.name }}`:

```
/ Test1
/ Test2
```

expected Output:

```
Test1
/Test2
```

Comment: Do those `bCrumb.name` contain slash or not?

Comment: yes it contains slash with them but i only want to remove slash from 1st variable.

Comment: you can check my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`

```
<div ng-repeat-start="bCrumb in bCrumbs" ng-if="$first>
    {{ beautify(bCrumb.name) }}
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat-end ng-if="!$first">
    {{ bCrumb.name }}
  </div>
```

Besides, define a function called `beautify` in your controller:

```
$scope.beautify = function (name) {
  return name.replace('/ ', '');
};
```

You can read the detailed documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points)

### update

A better way to handle string beautify is creating a filter to handle it

```
app.filter('beautify', function () {
    return function (data) {
        return data.replace("/ ", "");
    };
});
```

Then in your view template:

```
  <div ng-repeat-start="bCrumb in bCrumbs" ng-if="$first>
    {{ bCrumb.name | beautify }}
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat-end ng-if="!$first">
    {{ bCrumb.name }}
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it printing: undefinedTest1

Comment: @Mayur I have updated my answer with two possible solutions for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your controller (or whatever is producing `bCrumbs`) to strip the slashes before reaching view. This way it'll be more testable and (hopefully) clear. You could do something like this:

```
function strip(s) {
    if(s.indexOf('/ ') === 0) {
        return s.substring(2);
    } else {
        return s;
    }
}
$scope.bCrumbs = originalBCrumbs.map(function(bc, idx) {
    return idx === 0 ? strip(bc) : bc;
});
```